# How to mock a generic repository using NUnit.Mocks?

Tags: unit-testing, nunit, rhino-mocks, repository-pattern, generics

I'm working on a [generic repository](http://mikehadlow.blogspot.com/2008/03/using-irepository-pattern-with-linq-to.html) and I would like to test it using a NUnit.Mocks . According to Mike Hadlow in his article you can do it using Rhino mocks like this:

```
User[] users = new User[] { };
...
Expect.Call(userRepository.GetAll()).Return(users);
```

So I thought maybe I could write the same thing in NUnit.Mocks like this :

```
dataProviderMock = new DynamicMock(typeof(IDataProvider<User>));
var user = new User {Username = "username", Password = "password"};
var users =new[]{ user };
dataProviderMock.ExpectAndReturn("GetAll",users);
```

but I'm getting an InvalidCastException as I expected since there's no way to cast an array of users to an IQueryable.
So here's the question how can I mock an IQueryable using NUnit.Mocks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought :)
There is this AsQueryable() extension method that lets convert an array to an IQueryable.
So it doesn't matter if you are using Rhino Mocks or NUnit.Mocks.
Here's what i did :

```
dataProviderMock = new DynamicMock(typeof(IDataProvider<User>));
var user = new User {Username = "username", Password = "password"};
var users =new[]{ user };
dataProviderMock.ExpectAndReturn("GetAll",users.AsQueryable());
```